# Projection of compact set

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $X'$ be topological spaces and $B \subseteq X \times X'$ a compact subset of the product topology of $X$ and $X'$. Suppose $C \subseteq X$ is compact.

**Question:** Is $B[C] = \{ b \in X' \mid (a,b) \in B \text{ for some } a \in C \}$ compact in X'?

**Edit:** We can write $B[C] = \pi_2[(C \times X') \cap B]$, so it suffices to prove that $(C \times X') \cap B$ is compact. Note that we do *not* assume that $C$ is closed in $X$, only that it is compact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $B\cap (C\times X')$ is compact.

**Hint2:** $\pi_1: X\times X'\to X$ is continuous.

---

Edit: the above works in spaces where compact sets are all closed. If you don't have that assumption, here is a counterexample.

> Take $X=\{0,1\}$ endowed with the trivial topology $\{\emptyset, X\}$.
>
> Take $X'=\Bbb R$ endowed with the usual topology.
>
> The open sets for the product topology are exactly the sets of the form $X\times U$ where $U$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

**Claim:** the set $B=A_0\cup A_1$ is compact, where $A_0=\{0\}\times (-1,1)$ and $A_1=\{1\}\times [-2,2]$.

It is easy to derive from the compactness of $[-2,2]$ in $\Bbb R$.

Consider now $C=\{0\}$. It is trivially compact in $X$. But $B[C]=(-1,1)$ is not compact in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: I figured it suffices to prove that $B \cap (C \times X')$ is compact, but this is the part I struggle with because $C \times X'$ need not be closed in $X \times X'$.

Comment: I think you need to have that $C^c$ is open for your argument (i.e. $C$ is closed in $X$), but a compact set in a topological space need not be closed... Am I missing something?

Comment: @MathStudent020 No, you're right, I am thinking of a way around or a counterexample.

Comment: @MathStudent020 I think I have a counterexample.

Comment: Beautiful! I was trying to come op with a counterexample using the cofinite topology, but this is very clear.